# How to make background larger then screen and rotate it?

Tags: android, animation

Want to make space background to my activity and begin to rotate it slowly, but i stuck with that:
[screenshot (http://postimg.org/)](http://postimg.org/image/k7qenv5wx/)

The effect I need [need](http://postimg.org/image/5t5xoc63j/) I can get if add in XML file

```
android:scaleY="2"
android:scaleX="2"
```

but it will not work, android scale pic down when app start.

Guys, really need your help, I in android for 4 day and have bad english

----ADDED---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/backgroundd"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post what you have tried so far. I would recommend to use an image in a `RelativeLayout` and apply a recursive animation.

Comment: Can u be more detail about recursive animation?

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18016126/1369566) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, and I am not sure it is the best solution, but could you set a negative android:layout_marginon the image?

```
android:layout_margin="-100dp"
```

See here for more: [How to get a view larger than its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967096/how-to-get-a-view-larger-than-its-parent)

Also, posting your full XML could help us know more about how you are setting up the layout.